# When we compile C++ what do we get ? binary code ? assembleur code?

Tags: c++, compilation

In Java, when we compile a file, we get byte code which is then executed with the virtual machine.

How about in C++ ? What happens when we compile a file with g++, what do we get assembler code or binary code?

Comment: `g++` is a front-end program that calls other programs for the different stages of the build process. You can ask it to stop after pre-processing, code-creation (which results in assembler code), after object-file creation or let it build and link a fully executable programs.

Comment: thank you for your comment, you are right there is different stage on compilation process. What I don't get is : the final executable is it Assembleur code ou binary code ? or sommething else, without stopping g++ on any stage until I get the final executable.

Comment: As the program is directly executable, without any need for calling an assembler, then it should be easy to guess what kind of file the executable is.

Comment: @OSryx You get binary code that's executable by the CPU, but it's easy to view this binary code as assembly code with a disassembler, such as `objdump`. Assembly is more or less a human-readable version of binary machine code.

Comment: @DUman this is what I am looking for  "Assembly is more or less a human-readable version of binary machine code" :D

Comment: Guys can you compile your comments into an answer so that I accept it as an answer ? :)

Answer (score 3):

C and C++ are compiled into an object file. These files contain the machine code that can directly be executed on the target processor. However before being fully executable, we will need to link all the object files together. This does not change the code other than to fill in all the addresses for missing symbols. The format of the code remains the same.

On linux, the object files are in [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format.

One can however compile a file with link time optimizations. This will generally also produce a bytecode in addition to the machine code. When one links with link time optimization, the linker will then convert the byte code into machine code while performing cross compilation unit (object file) optimization.

Comment: When you say *machine code* you mean "binary code which can be read as assembleur code" ?

Comment: I mean the binary code that can be directly executed by the processor. This is most often easily disassembled into human readable assembly.